# Azure Active Directory B2C - AADB2C - AADB2C90079: Clients must send a client_secret when redeeming a confidential grant

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am developing for the first time against an Azure Active Directory B2C. I am developing a WPF/Desktop Application.

Signing in and Signing Out has been working perfectly until inexplicably today it stopped working and is now throwing the following exception during sign in.

```
AADB2C90079: Clients must send a client_secret when redeeming a confidential grant.
```

There is a suggestion that I need to refresh a token as outlined in this stack overflow question:
[Azure B2C Custom Policies: Invalid Request, client secret error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044743/azure-b2c-custom-policies-invalid-request-client-secret-error)

**But I haven't the slightest clue how to do this.**

Here is my Sign-In Code (Await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(...) is what raises the exception)

```
Public Async Function SignIn() As Task(Of Boolean)

    Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = Nothing
    Dim accounts As IEnumerable(Of IAccount) = Await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync()

    Try
        authResult = Await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(ApiScopes, GetUserByPolicy(accounts, PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.SelectAccount, String.Empty, Nothing, Authority)
        userProf = Await GetUserInformation()
        SignInState = SignInStateEnum.SignedIn
        Return True
    Catch ex As MsalServiceException

        Try
            If ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118") Then
                authResult = PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(ApiScopes, GetUserByPolicy(accounts, PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.SelectAccount, String.Empty, Nothing, AuthorityResetPassword).Result
                userProf = GetUserInformation().Result
                SignInState = SignInStateEnum.SignedIn
                Return True
            Else
                logger.Error($"Error Acquiring Token:{Environment.NewLine}{ex}")
                logger.Error("Exception Raised", ex)
                userProf = Nothing
                SignInState = SignInStateEnum.SignedOut
                Return False
            End If
        Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
            logger.Error("Exception Raised", __unusedException1__)
            userProf = Nothing
            SignInState = SignInStateEnum.SignedOut
            Return False
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Error($"Users:{String.Join(",", accounts.[Select](Function(u) u.Username))}{Environment.NewLine}Error Acquiring Token:{Environment.NewLine}{ex}")
        logger.Error("Exception Raised", ex)
        userProf = Nothing
        SignInState = SignInStateEnum.SignedOut
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been identified as an Azure issue
This is the message I got from Azure support:
"The issue was found to be a backend issue. Our product team has found the issue and deployed the fix. could you please try again and let me know whether it is working for your tenant now?"